# Plugin with id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, grgit

I'm trying to compile an opensource minecraft mod called `VeinMiner`.
I use `./gradlew build` to compile it.
However it failed and give me this reason:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/xxxx/Desktop/VeinMiner/build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'VeinMiner'.
> Plugin with id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.778 secs
```

I have tried to git clone it again or run it in sudo.
However, neither of these two work.

This build gradle is like this:
**(It's too long so I select some part of it)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.matthewprenger.cursegradle' version '1.0.7'
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '1.3.2'
}

apply plugin: 'forge'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "org.ajoberstar.grgit"
apply plugin: "com.matthewprenger.cursegradle"

ext.git = grgit.open(file('.'))

ext {
    configFile = file "build.properties"

    revision = git.head().abbreviatedId
    depth = git.log().size()
}
```

I expected to Build Successful. Have anyone met this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mentioned plugin `org.ajoberstar.grgit` gets applied twice. The first time it gets applied via the new `plugins` block, the second time via the old `apply plugin:` method. Simply remove the line `apply plugin: "org.ajoberstar.grgit"` and the error should disappear.

To apply plugins via the old `apply plugin:` method, the plugin package needs to be resolved from an arbitrary repository inside the `buildscript` block. This works in the same way as resolving project dependencies via the normal `repositories` and `dependencies` blocks.

The new `plugins` block directly resolves plugins from the [Gradle plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) and applies them in the same step.

I would guess that the way how to apply to plugin was changed to the newer one, but the removal of the old method did not happen. In existing setups the plugin may have been resolved from the local Gradle cache, but on your new setup it could not be found.